# functional integration testing

Tags: testing, integration, functional-programming

Is software testing done in the following order?

1. Unit testing
2. Integration testing
3. Functional testing

I want to confirm if Functional testing is done after Integration testing or not.

Thanx

Comment: Is this "how should it be done" or "how is it actually done"?  'Cause I know far too many people working at companies where they only do unit tests once a bug is found.

Comment: Both... "how it should be done" and "how it actually done"?

Answer (score 2):

That is a logical ordering, yes. Often followed by User Acceptance Testing and then any form of public alpha/beta testing before release if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In a TDD coding environment, the order in which these tests are made to pass generally follows your order; however, they are often WRITTEN in the reverse order.

When a team gets a set of requirements, one of the first things they should do is turn those requirements into one or more automated acceptance tests, which prove that the system meets all functional requirements defined. When this test passes, you're done (IF you wrote it properly). The test, when first written, obviously shouldn't pass. It may not even compile, if it references new object types that you haven't defined yet.

Once the test is written, the team can usually see what is required to make it pass at a high level, and break up development along these lines. Along the way, integration tests (which test the interaction of objects with each other) and unit tests (which test small, atomic pieces of functionality in near-complete isolation from other code) are written. Using refactoring tools like ReSharper, the code of these tests can be used to create the objects and even the logic of the functionality being tested. If you're testing that the output of A+B is C, then assert that A+B == C, then extract a method from that logic in the test fixture, then extract a class containing that method. You now have an object with a method you can call that produces the right answer.

Along the way, you have also tested the requirements: if the requirements assert that an answer, given A and B, must be the logical equivalent of 1+2==5, then the requirements have an inconsistency indicating a need for further clarification (i.e. somebody forgot to mention that D=2 should be added to B before A+B == C) or a technical impossibility (i.e. the calculation requires there to be 25 hours in a day or 9 bits in a byte). It may be impossible (and is generally considered infeasible by Agile methodologies) to guarantee without a doubt that you have removed all of these inconsistencies from the requirements before any development begins.